# #SQL, #oracle#testing

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query is union of 2 different joins on same tables
I want to right a negative sql query to identify the rows that dont satisfy the below query (both condition)

```
SELECT  A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, A.col4, A.col5
FROM TAB1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2 B
ON A.col6 = B.col7
WHERE A.col6 IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT  A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, A.col4, A.col5
FROM TAB1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2 B
ON A.col1 = B.col1
WHERE A.col6 IS NULL;
```

the above query is a part of SRC sql which does union on the above 2 datasets and then does partition of the ranks by the columns in above sql, I am adding a staging layer to identify the bad data , So trying to get the sql to identify the data from  TAB1 which dont have corresponding data in Tab2

Answer (score 0):

> trying to get the sql to identify the data from TAB1 which dont have corresponding data in Tab2

To me, that looks like a candidate for the `minus` set operator.

For example (based on Scott's sample schema as it contains some data; you didn't post any so - it is easier to illustrate it that way):

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno order by deptno;

    DEPTNO   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
        10          3
        20          5
        30          6
```

Departments that exist in `dept` table, but don't exist in `emp` table:

```
SQL> select deptno from dept
  2  minus
  3  select deptno from emp;

    DEPTNO
----------
        40

SQL>
```

---

Your query contains bunch of dummy column and table names so I can't really suggest how should query - that would return data you're looking for - look like. If you posted some sample data and desired result, that would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The queries care about different rows of tab1. The first query looks for rows where col6 is not null, the second query looks for rows where col6 is null. So, `UNION [DISTINCT]` on the two queries doesn't make too much sense, at first glance, because there shouldn't be any duplicates to remove.

But in both queries you are outer joining the table tab2. As you only select columns from table tab1, though, all you achieve by this is that you get all tab1 rows and possibly many duplicates. By using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` you remove these duplicates again. So it is not really that you remove duplicates cause by unioning two queries, which is what `UNION [DISTINCT]` is made for, but you make the two data sets distinct.

Your query can hence be shortened to:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM tab1;
```

because for all rows col6 is either null or not.

Now you say you want the opposite, all rows that don't satisfy the condition. But there is no condition. The opposite of selecting all rows would be no rows, e.g.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM tab1 WHERE ROWNUM = 0;
```

At the end of your request you say

> So trying to get the sql to identify the data from TAB1 which dont have corresponding data in Tab2

You may simply be looking for this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM tab1
WHERE (col6 IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.col7 = tab1.col6)
   OR (col6 IS     NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.col1 = tab1.col1);
```

Whenever you want to check whether data exists or not in another table, don't join, but use `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`.